# SplitLayoutPanel inside DisclosurePanel

Tags: gwt, uibinder

When nesting a SplitLayoutPanel inside a DisclosurePanel the SplitLayoutPanel is not displayed, when openening the DisclosurePanel using relative height attributes (e.g., 100%). Inspecting the generated HTML yields that the row containing the SplitLayoutPanel (DisclosurePanel produces a table with two rows) has a height of 0px, but the width is determined correctly.

Am I doing something completely wrong? Removing the DisclosurePanel displays the SplitLayoutPanel correctly. Also setting the height of the SplitLayoutPanel to a absolute value (e.g., 500px) works.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui="urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder" xmlns:g="urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui">
<g:DisclosurePanel width="99%">
    <g:header>Some Header</g:header>
    <g:SplitLayoutPanel ui:field="mySplitLayoutPanel"
        width="100%" height="100%">
        <g:west size="200">
            <g:ScrollPanel ui:field="streamTreePanel" styleName="ccTreePanel" />
        </g:west>
        <g:center>
            <g:VerticalPanel ui:field="streamTablePanel"
                styleName="ccTablePanel" width="100%" />
        </g:center>
        <g:east size="400">
            <g:ScrollPanel ui:field="streamInfoPanel" styleName="ccInfoPanel" />
        </g:east>
    </g:SplitLayoutPanel>
</g:DisclosurePanel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LayoutPanels` require that an unbroken chain of `ProvidesResize` and `RequiresResize` parent widgets up to the `RootLayoutPanel` to work properly. 
In your case `DisclosurePanel` doesn't implement any of the interfaces.
You can either:

- put your `SplitLayoutPanel` into a [ResizeLayoutPanel](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/ResizeLayoutPanel.html)
- specify explicit dimensions in your `DisclosurePanel` (see Recipes for more info)
- add your own `ResizeHandler` and resize the `SplitLayoutPanel` manually (call `onResize()`).